# Java - Get value of attribute in a class

Tags: java

Suppose this piece of code:

```
public class Int {
    public int value;

    public Int () {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public Int (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return Integer.valueOf (this.value).toString ();
    }
}
```

Using a public attribute, I can access to the value of the attribute using:

```
Int a = new Int ();
int x = a.value;
```

I want to ask if there is a way to make this:

```
Int a = new Int (3);
Int b = new Int (11);

int x = a + b;
```

instead of:

```
...
int x = a.value + b.value;
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, mea culpa! I know that Java does not support operator overloading. I wrote bad examples.

```
Int a = new Int (12);
int x = a.value;
```

There is a way where I can write the code above in this way?

```
Int a = new Int (12);
int x = a;
```

So, what I'm asking is if it's possible to access to a specific attribute of a class omitting the name of the attribute.

Comment: Not in Java. In Scala for example, you can if you defined a method `+(that: Int): Int`, Then you can write `Int x = a + b` which is equivalent to the method call `Int x = a.+(b)`

Comment: You ask about _operator overloading_ in Java.

Comment: after you edit also the answer remains **NO**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that Java does not support user-specified operator overloading, there is also no mechanism to do [auto-(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) with your own classes.

Auto-(un)boxing only works with the 8 standard wrapper classes (`Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`) as defined in [paragraph 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) of the Java Language Specification.

So there is no way to make this work:

```
// Your own class Int
class Int { ... }

Int x = new Int(12);
int y = x; // auto-unboxing, not possible with Int
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow operator overloading (except fot Strings), so the `+` operator cannot be used to "add" custom classes like your `Int`.

Which means that, in your case, you cannot use the `+` operator to do `Int x = a + b;`.

The correct way to do this in an Object-Oriented language like Java, would be to add a `plus` (or `add`) method to you `Int` class to perform this operation :

```
public Int plus(Int other) {
    return new Int(this.value + other.value);
}
```

EDIT : to answer your new question...

The answer is still no, you can't define custom boxing/unboxing rules. The compiler will compare the type of the reference (`int`) to the type of the instance (the custom `Int` class), find they are not in the same hierarchy, and emit a compilation error.

The rules that allow the `Number` wrappers (`Integer`, `Long`, etc.) to be seamlessly transformed to/from primitive types are special exceptions documented in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: ... Or Boxed primitives. Which can be auto unboxed